# Why can't I change the array element-by-element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array and a class

```
let questions = [
    {
        questionText: '',
        answerOptions: [],
    },
];


class Questions {
constructor(questionText,answerOptions) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.answerOptions = [answerOptions];
}
```

}

I fill them out through the form and when I click on the button I try to fill in the array

```
   const pressSave = () => {
    //check
    const correctNum = newAnswerCorrect

    if (correctNum<0){
        return
    }

    if (newQuestion.question === ""){
        return
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < newAnswer.answers.length; i++) { // выведет 0, затем 1, затем 2
        if (newAnswer.answers[i].answerText === ""){
            return
        }
    }

    const answArray = [
        {
            answerText: newAnswer.answers[0]?.answerText, isCorrect: false
       },
        {
            answerText: newAnswer.answers[1]?.answerText, isCorrect: false
        },
        {
            answerText: newAnswer.answers[2]?.answerText, isCorrect: false
        },
        {
            answerText: newAnswer.answers[3]?.answerText, isCorrect: false
        }
    ]
    answArray[correctNum].isCorrect = true

    if (currentQuestion === 0){


        questions[0] =  new Questions(
            newQuestion.question,
            answArray
        )
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
        console.log("Is 0 element")
        console.log(questions)
        return questions

    }

    
    questions[currentQuestion] =  new Questions(
        newQuestion.question,
        answArray
    )
    setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
    console.log("Is", currentQuestion, "element")
    console.log(questions)
    return questions
}
```

The first element is added well

[image: first]

But if you try to add something again, it happens that everything is erased

[image: second]

Why?

I'm trying to supplement it through a form that looks like this
[image: it]

[image: error]

**here's** what happens if you try to add an element many times, the 0th element has a body, + many empty elements, and + the last correct element

[Here is the github, here is all the code, I do not know how to provide access to the sandbox in another way](https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms/blob/master/client/src/pages/QuizGameCreator.js)

Comment: can you give some sample code on sandbox for debugging

Comment: seems like your `let questions = ..` is executed every time. where is it located?

Comment: i can give https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms

Comment: @Turo at the very beginning

Comment: For what I see, how the `Questions` constructor is implemented and used, the implementation should change from  `this.answerOptions = [answerOptions];` to   `this.answerOptions = [...answerOptions];`. And there are many more possible sources of error within the provided code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sandbox of this project for debugging could give a better answer.
But my guess is that you define this `questions` variable in a local function or in the component itself, which makes it be assigned the:

```
let questions = [
    {
        questionText: '',
        answerOptions: [],
    },
];
```

each time the component renders.

Edit: please next time add the whole component.
The reason you encounter it is because you've put the `let questions = ...` at the beginning of the function, so each time it renders you over ride the `questions` value.
You could quick fix it by putting this assignment outside the functional component. But I wouldn't recommend this kind of global variable. I would suggest you would hold the questions as a state, i.e
`const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<Questions[]>([])`
and change the state by add the new question to the state.

Please ignore this answer if you've defined it as a global variable.

Comment: added, there is all the code, I do not know how to provide access to the sandbox in another way

Comment: You're right, I should have just moved the code to a higher level, I'm sitting here racking my brain and can't guess

Comment: yes! Everything is working now! @PeterSeliger